# Combining two Pandas DataFrames to a three-dimensional np.array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to concatinate two pandas DataFrames to a threedimensional np.array. For example these DataFrames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10, 20, 30], 'col2': [40,50,60]})
```

should be concatinated to the np.array `[[[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]],[[4,40],[5,50],[6,60]]]`.

My initial idea is to zip the DataFrames using this formula:

```
dfnew=df1.copy()

for i in range(len(dfnew.columns)):

dfnew[dfnew.columns[i]]=list(map(list, zip(df1.iloc[:,i],df2.iloc[:,i])))
```

Unfourtunaly, this doesn't work as it creates a twodimensiona array containing a list:

```
array([[list([1, 10]), list([4, 40])],
       [list([2, 20]), list([5, 50])],
       [list([3, 30]), list([6, 60])]], dtype=object)

np.array(dfnew).shape -> (3,2)
```

As the shape of the array is not threedimensional, I can't use the array in the following process.

Could you please help me converting the twodimensional array into a threedimensional one or do you have any other approach to the problem.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
result = np.array([np.transpose(i) for i in zip(df1.to_numpy().T, df2.to_numpy().T)])
```